# Adding data to typed datasets programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

Why I get a "there is no row at position 0" exception:

```
DSGeneral dg = new DSGeneral();

// I create 1 table
DSGeneral.GeneralDataTable t = new DSGeneral.GeneralDataTable();
dg.Tables.Add(t);

// The 1st row
DSGeneral.GeneralRow r = t.NewGeneralRow();
r.Code = "code";
r.Value = "7";
t.Rows.Add(r);

// The 2nd row
DSGeneral.GeneralRow r2 = t.NewGeneralRow();
r2.Code = "exp";
r2.Value = "5";
t.Rows.Add(r2);
```

It throws here:

```
int numClave = Convert.ToInt16(dg.General[0].Value);
```

Furthermore, debugging I could see that my typed dataset `dg` has 2 tables, I wonder why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are using [strongly typed `DataSets`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esbykkzb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you declare the tables and dataadapters on the designer. The `DataTables` then are already part of that `DataSets`, hence you don't need to to add them again to it.

That explains why the dataset contains two tables instead of one. Because of the same reason you get the exception. You have added the rows to your manually created table and not to the declaratively added.

But

```
 dg.General[0].Rows[0].Value
```

accesses the auto-generated `DataTable` which is still empty.

So you just have to use the available table:

```
DSGeneral dg = new DSGeneral();
DSGeneral.GeneralRow r = dg.General.NewGeneralRow();
r.Code = "code";
r.Value = "7";
dg.General.AddGeneralRow(r);
```

Comment: I edited the code without the `Add()`for both tables and rows but now it says that there a no rows when I do `dg.General.Rows.Count`

Comment: @a_maar: Yes, of course you still have to add the rows to the `DataTable`. Only the tables exist and not the rows.

Comment: @a_maar: Edited my answer to clarify that. There must be an auto-generated method `AddGeneralRow` that you can use to add your strongly typed `DataRow`.